Why doesn't iron burn?
Iron is clearly capable of oxidizing, causing rust to be formed.
This seems to me to be a combustion reaction, as oxygen is bonded to the $\ce{Fe}$ atom. So why doesn't iron burn when exposed to fire or heat?

I guess using Brillo pads to start fires didn’t actually work? The issue is the oxide formation on the surface keeping fresh iron being available for the reaction. High surface area to volume forms (thin wire, powders) most certainly burn nicely.

Iron has a protective oxide layer meaning It doesn't burn that easily. Also rusting is not combustion, it is oxidation

@user155568 what's the difference? I thought combustion is a special case of oxidation, specifically where oxygen is the oxidiser.

Combustion is a high temperature exothermic reaction between fuel and oxidant - usually oxygen. Oxidation is when a species is oxidized (loses electrons / gains oxygen)

Iron burns ! It is easy to show. I have done it plenty of times in my class room or in public. The only problem is to improve the contact between iron and air. The best way to do it is to use steel wool. This is the sort of iron wire pads that is used to clean wooden floors or the floor boards. It is made of extremely fine wires, a couple of microns wide. To show that this pad burns, you lighten it with a match or a Bunsen flam. You hold it with a clip or pliers. And you move this burning pad through the air around you. This burns quickly without flames. The emitted light is visible far away.

https://edurev.in/question/640447/Is-iron-nail-a-combustible-material--

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/133687/how-can-i-have-iron-powder-without-a-fast-reaction-with-oxygen

Iron does burn, if the circumstances are right
Iron does burn and quite well if the conditions are right, like many other easily oxidisable metals.
This is easy to test as Maurice points out in a comment with steel wool. Or by sprinkling iron filings into a hot flame which will create a shower of sparks.
But what is the main reason a block of iron does not burn when heated in a flame?
There are several, many of which also apply to far more flammable metals like magnesium or aluminium.
Some example situations might clarify the reasons. A standard school demonstration is to burn magnesium strip to get a very bright, strong, hard to extinguish flame. But it is essentially impossible to set fire to a lump of magnesium (luckily since some high end laptops have magnesium frames and intel processors ;-) ). These are not a fire hazard. Aluminium is about as reactive but even foil is not easily ignitable, though finely divided aluminium is a key ingredient in thermite which one ignited, "burns" with great heat. But bulk aluminium cooking utensils don't catch fire even when treated carelessly.
Two main reasons prevent easy burning in all three metals. One is the oxide layer on the surface. This is strongest on aluminium but has some affect in magnesium and iron. But that can't be the whole story as the burning ability of powders of the metals would not happen were this the primary explanation (and rust is weak protection against further iron oxidation).
A simpler and more important explanation is that bulk metals are good heat conductors and it is almost impossible to rapidly heat a small portion of the metal to a temperature hot enough to cause ignition in air. The ignition temperatures are often well above the melting point, making this even harder (aluminium, magnesium and iron can all be cast into ingots in air, though inert gases are often used in magnesium casting to protect the quality the casts and small splashes of liquid magnesium will ignite).
This factor is also interacts with the state of the metal. Small particles have both a larger surface area so exposing more of the metal surface to air and are far easier to heat rapidly to the ignition temperature as there is nowhere for the heat to go when the particle are isolated (in the bulk metal local heat is rapidly conducted away to other parts of the metal).
Compare this with why some forms of carbon make good fuels and others do not: Why is coal and charcoal a good fuel, but not graphite?.
